# Umbraco 3.0 to latest version migration

Tags: umbraco

We have Live Site running with Umbraco 3.0 version. Now, we want to use latest Umbraco V4.7. We need to know how it is possible? Is there any Open Source OR Free Tool which can support this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to each major version in succession.  First, upgrade from 3.0 to 4.0, then 4.0 to 4.5.2, then to 4.7.

If you need help I have a blog post recording the process I have done from 4.0 to 4.7.

[Notes and Experiences Upgrading Umbraco 4.0.x to 4.6.1 and 4.7.0](http://www.proworks.com/blog/2011/03/03/my-notes-and-experiences-upgrading-umbraco-4-0-x-to-4-6-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a package of your current site, this can be done with the help of `Developer section -> packages -> create package` in umbraco.
Then in ver4.7 install that package again in a blank site, your prevoius site should be up.